# How to install subversion using homebrew on OSX

Tags: macos, svn, osx-mountain-lion, homebrew

i tried

```
$ brew install subversion
```

and see

```
Error: Cannot write to /usr/local/Cellar
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: svn (although a really old version) comes on your mac.  what version are you trying to install?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the permissions on `/usr/local/Cellar/`.

Answer (score 6):

Your `/usr/local/Cellar/` is not writable to brew. Check permissions on that folder.

```
ls -lA /usr/local/ | grep Cellar

# dr-xr-xr-x   18 *****  admin    612 Feb 18 08:47 Cellar
#   ^  ^  ^
```

In this case it needs write permissions:

```
chmod u+rw /usr/local/Cellar/
```

It's also possible the folder is owned by `root`.

```
ls -lA /usr/local/ | grep Cellar

# drwxr-xr-x   18 root  root    612 Feb 18 08:47 Cellar
#                 ^^^^  ^^^^
```

In this case you need to change the owner:

```
chown $(whoami):admin /usr/local/Cellar/
```

And you may have to do both the `chown` and `chmod` commands.

This is typically caused by running `brew` with `sudo` (`sudo brew install subversion`). *You generally don't want to do this.* brew should ask for your password if it needs to sudo and this will give folders and files the correct permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the
ownership and permissions
Please
Try

```
sudo chown -R `whoami`:admin /usr/local/*
```

Answer (score -3):

Try

**`sudo`**`brew install subversion`

Comment: This is the hammer solution. I successfully resolved the issue by setting the correct permissions on the folder /usr/local/Cellar.

Comment: Why hammer solution? It is quite usual case that you have to ask for root permission to install new things...  At least in Unix like systems...

Comment: This doesn't even work anymore. Homebrew responds to sudo with: ```Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.```